# Slow query msg using python motor client and mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, kubernetes, python-asyncio

I have a MongoDB pod with millions of records in k8s and using `AsyncIOMotorClient` to iterate over the cursor with `1000` batch size. However, after a few iterations, the fetching got stuck and I can see the `Slow query` message from MongoDB logs.

The iteration is like below after getting collection:

```
cursor = collection.aggregate_raw_batches(pipeline=pipeline, batchSize=c['QUERY_BATCH_SIZE'])


async for batch in cursor:

    ...
```

Even I tried to paginate the fetched records by adding `$skip` `$limit` into pipeline, but the same result appears again.

I also tried to track resource usage such as CPU or memory in Kubernetes but everything looks fine except MongoDB itself.

Example log of MongoDB:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-24T13:02:41.042+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn1214224","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"product.feed_1648113467","command":{"getMore":4946197083994343333,"collection":"feed_1648113467","batchSize":1000,"lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"bec21ebb-f305-4438-8e1d-16badfc22bd3"}},"$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":{"$timestamp":{"t":1648126959,"i":1}},"signature":{"hash":{"$binary":{"base64":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=","subType":"0"}},"keyId":0}},"$db":"product"},"originatingCommand":{"aggregate":"feed_1648113467","pipeline":[{"$match":{"_disapproved":{"$ne":true},"_gpla_feed_name":"detske-zbozi/kocarky","_delivery.direct":true,"$or":[{"_restricted":{"$ne":true}},{"_restriction_exception_for_google":true}]}},{"$limit":1000000},{"$project":{"_id":0,"g:description":1,"g:id":1,"title":"$g:name","g:price":{"$concat":[{"$toString":"$g:price_rounded"}," CZK"]},"g:brand":"$g:producer_name","g:image_link":"$g:image_url","g:additional_image_link":1,"link":"$g:url","g:availability":"in stock","g:condition":"new","g:material":1,"g:color":1,"g:gender":1,"g:size":1,"g:product_type":1,"g:google_product_category":1,"g:energy_efficiency_class":1,"g:unit_pricing_measure":1,"g:unit_pricing_base_measure":1,"g:gtin":"$g:ean","g:adult":"$_restricted","g:product_detail":1}}],"cursor":{"batchSize":0},"lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"bec21ebb-f305-4438-8e1d-16badfc22bd3"}},"$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":{"$timestamp":{"t":1648126959,"i":1}},"signature":{"hash":{"$binary":{"base64":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=","subType":"0"}},"keyId":0}},"$db":"product","$readPreference":{"mode":"primaryPreferred"}},"planSummary":"IXSCAN { _disapproved: 1, _gpla_feed_name: 1 }","cursorid":4946197083994343333,"keysExamined":861,"docsExamined":859,"cursorExhausted":true,"numYields":8,"nreturned":960,"reslen":642671,"locks":{"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":9}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":9}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"r":9}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"r":9}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}},"storage":{"data":{"bytesRead":21129204,"timeReadingMicros":112254}},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":138}}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: it is important to add what are your available indexes  and document example , btw 138 ms seems not such a big value  , also the field _disapproved seems not very selective for first field in compound index , maybe better if _gpla_feed_name is your first field in the index ?

Comment: Actually, that gave me an idea about removing the filters from the query and it worked. But I need to have some filtering like below which slows down things currently: `{'_top_order': {'$lte': 5},'g:top': {'$lte': 5},'_disapproved': {'$ne': True}}`